# Reading key with greatest number from set

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have a set of maps as below

```
#{{:uid 2, :name "book2", :qty "2", :price "2"} {:uid 3, :name "book3", :price "1", :qty "1"}  
  {:uid 1, :name "book4", :qty "2", :price "2"}}
```

Now I want to read value of `:uid` with greatest number, so in this example I want to get `3`.

Can anyone guide me how can I fetch this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `reduce`

```
(reduce #(max %1 (:uid %2)) 0 #{{:uid 2, :name "book2", :qty "2", :price "2"}
                                {:uid 3, :name "book3", :price "1", :qty "1"}})
```

Assuming the uids are non-negative.

EDIT:

It would be better to use a different starting value for the accumulator as recommended by @Thumbnail.

```
(reduce #(max %1 (:uid %2)) (Long/MIN_VALUE) #{{:uid 2, :name "book2", :qty "2", :price "2"}
                                               {:uid 3, :name "book3", :price "1", :qty "1"}})
```

This should work with negatives as well.

Comment: Use `Long/MIN_VALUE` as the initial value instead of `0`?

Answer (score 2):

The built in [`sorted-set-by`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-set-by) function should do the trick:

```
user> (apply sorted-set-by  
     #(- (:uid %1) (:uid %2)) 
     #{{:uid 2, :name "book2", :qty "2", :price "2"} 
       {:uid 3, :name "book3", :price "1", :qty "1"}  
       {:uid 1, :name "book4", :qty "2", :price "2"}})
#{{:uid 1, :name "book4", :qty "2", :price "2"} 
  {:uid 2, :name "book2", :qty "2", :price "2"} 
  {:uid 3, :name "book3", :qty "1", :price "1"}}
```

then take the last one (or reverse the %1 and %2 comparator). Of course the usual trade-offs apply if for instance you where only going to get the value once and or it was a small set then a linear scan would be more efficient.

PS: I changed the data so all the uids are the same type

Answer (score 2):

You could also use max-key

```
(:uid (apply max-key
        :uid
        #{{:uid 2, :name "book2", :qty "2", :price "2"} {:uid 3, :name "book3", :price "1", :qty "1"}
          {:uid 1, :name "book4", :qty "2", :price "2"}}))
```

This wouldn't work if the data was as given though, as the uids seem to be strings in some and numbers in other maps.  Also, if the set was empty, this would fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the number,

```
(defn max-uid [coll] (apply max (map :uid coll)))
```

will supply it.

```
(max-uid #{{:uid 2, :name "book2", :qty "2", :price "2"}
           {:uid 3, :name "book3", :price "1", :qty "1"}  
           {:uid 1, :name "book4", :qty "2", :price "2"}})

;3
```